# How to install maxmind geoLite2 on amazon linux with php server?

Tags: php, maxmind, geolite2

I am facing a problem while installing maxmind GeoLite2 free country lookup via IP on my server. Truly, I didn't found any good steps to install it. Can any one please suggest to me a right solution to install it on aws elastic beanstalk linux php machine. Thanks.